# Specify loops in python using an arithmetic operation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to specify for loop in python.for example N=435
for loop should be run for 100,200,300,400,435..for all value of N.It should like this.That divide the value of N/100 for each loop..and finally 35 will remain so that final loop value should be 435..is is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard range() function is close, but it doesn't emit the final value. An option is to write your own range wrapper that does. In python 3 the `range` function is an iterator, but in 2.x you need to use `xrange` if you want the iterator version.

```
>>> def deranged(n):
...     for i in xrange(100, n, 100):
...             yield i
...     yield n
... 
>>> for i in deranged(435):
...     print i
... 
100
200
300
400
435
```

Comment: In Python 2.x it might be better to use `xrange()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to python.

```
n=435
e=0


if(n>100):
    e=n/100
    if(e>0):
        for x in range(1,e+1):
            print(100 * x)
        print(n)
```